# Draw mean and outlier points for box plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the outliers and mean point for the box plots in below using the data available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7147744/fp_combined_melted.log). The dataset has 3 different factors and 1 value column for 3600 rows.

While I run the below the code it shows the mean point but doesn't draw the outliers properly

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Representations, y=Values, fill=Methods)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~Metrics) +  
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="black", geom="point", position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Again, while I am modify the code like in below the mean points disappear !!

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Representations, y=Values, colour=Methods)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~Metrics) +  
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="black", geom="point", position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

In both of the cases I am getting the message: "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead" 3 times.

Any kind suggestions how to fix it? I would like to draw the mean points within individual box plots and show outliers in the same colour as the plots.

**EDIT:**
The original data set does not have any outliers and that was reason for my confusion. Thanks to MrFlick's answer with randomly generated data which clarifies it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than downloading the data, I just made a random sample.

```
set.seed(18)

gg <- expand.grid (
    Methods=c("BC","FD","FDFND","NC"),
    Metrics=c("DM","DTI","LB"),
    Representations=c("CHG","QR","HQR")
)

df <- data.frame(
    gg,
    Values=rnorm(nrow(gg)*50)
)
```

Then you should be able to create the plot you want with

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Representations, y=Values, fill=Methods)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", 
        position=position_dodge(width=0.75), color="white") + 
    facet_wrap(~Metrics)
```

which gave me

[image: boxplot]

I was using ggplot2 version 0.9.3.1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also later found that my data doesn't have any outlier according to the way ggplot2 calculates the outlier and that was the reason for confusion !!! And thanks for the nice example with random data, it also helped me a lot :)